# Verilog to Logic Diagram

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

I am trying to draw the logic diagram of this Verilog Code of a counter using mux, d flip flop, nand, and.

```
module CNT1 (Q, QN, To, CLK, D, L, RB, Ti);
output Q, QN, To;
input CLK, D, L, RB, Ti;
reg q, tout;
function mux;
input [3:0] in;
input [1:0] s;
case(s)
2'b00: mux=in[0];
2'b01: mux=in[1];
2'b10: mux=in[2];
2'b11: mux=in[3];
endcase
endfunction
always @(RB) begin
if (!RB)
assign q=1'b0;
else
deassign q;
end
always @(posedge CLK) q=mux({D,D,~q,q},{L,Ti});
always @(Ti or q) tout=Ti&q;
assign To=tout;
assign Q=q;
assign QN=~q;
endmodule
```

I have drawn this but I am not sure. Do you have a suggestion related to logic diagram of this code?

[image]

Comment: please take the time to properly crop your image. And take a sharp one. Or draw it using the circuit editor here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by tidying up the code. Whitespace makes it readable.

```
module CNT1 (Q, QN, To, CLK, D, L, RB, Ti);
    output Q, QN, To;
    input CLK, D, L, RB, Ti;

    reg q, tout;

    function mux;
        input [3:0] in;
        input [1:0] s;
    begin
        case(s)
            2'b00: mux=in[0];
            2'b01: mux=in[1];
            2'b10: mux=in[2];
            2'b11: mux=in[3];
        endcase
    end endfunction

    always @(RB) begin
        if (!RB) begin
            assign q=1'b0;
        end else begin
            deassign q;
        end
    end
    always @(posedge CLK) begin
        q = mux({D,D,~q,q},{L,Ti});
    end

    always @(Ti or q) begin
        tout = Ti&q;
    end

    assign To=tout;

    assign Q=q;
    assign QN=~q;

endmodule
```

Next you can start breaking it down. Lets look at the three always blocks first. From the bottom up:

```
always @(Ti or q) begin
    tout = Ti & q;
end
```

That's fairly straight forward. Just an AND gate. Your diagram successfully identifies this.

Next up:

```
always @(posedge CLK) begin
    q = mux({D,D,~q,q},{L,Ti});
end
```

That one is a bit more awkward as it uses a function call. Now looking at the function you can see that it is nothing more than a mux (as the name suggests) that has 4 data inputs, and a 2-bit select. Every time there is **a positive clock edge, `q` is updated** with the output of the mux.

This block is one place where your diagram goes wrong. We have the following assignment statements:

```
assign Q = q;
assign QN = ~q;
```

Because `Q = q`, your `Q` output in your diagram should *not* be the mux output, but the register output. Additionally you are missing the `QN` output which is the inverse of `q`.

Finally we have:

```
always @(RB) begin
    if (!RB) begin
        assign q=1'b0;
    end else begin
        deassign q;
    end
end
```

This is ugly in my opinion. It is using something called "Procedural Continuous Assignment". What the block is saying is if `RB` is `0`, **force the output of `q` to `0`**. When `RB` goes to `1`, **release the output `q`**.

The key term here is "release". When a signal is released, it will **hold it's value until another block updates it**.

This means it is *not* inferring a mux, because a mux would immediately change the value back to `q` after the signal is released, whereas the behaviour we need is to hold the current value until next time `q` is changed.

This behaviour is actually an asynchronous **reset** signal. The equivalent code for `q`, combining both always blocks to make it far more readable is:

```
always @(posedge CLK or negedge RB) begin
    if (!RB) begin
        q = 1'b0;
    end else begin
        q = mux({D,D,~q,q},{L,Ti});
    end
end
```

You should now be able to correct and complete your logic diagram.

Comment: I have tried to run this code in Xilinx Vivado 2017.2 but it gave error. Can you check it? https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Verilog-Counter-Code-Error/td-p/821840

Comment: @bieaisar "Procedural Continuous Assignment" like this is not supported for synthesis, hence I called it ugly. Replace with the equivalent asynchronous reset code.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an idea to establish logic diagram automatically using this code?

Comment: Search for "RTL Netlist Viewer"

Comment: `q` should be assigned with non-blocking (`<=`).

Comment: @Greg makes no difference. I've left it as per the original code. Blocking assignments are just as valid for synchronous logic as non-blocking assignments. Mixing the two in the same block is bad.

Comment: @TomCarpenter , my original comment (which I was not specific enough) was only suggesting to use non-blocking with your flip-flop with asynchronous reset example. I agree with you 99%. However, blocking assignments to synchronous logic allows a potential race condition in RTL simulation, resulting in a behavioral difference between RTL and post-synthesis. This code doesn't have this risk, though I still advocate following best coding practices so anyone learning will pick up good coding habits.